# Redirect index.php does not load css with slash in PHP url parameters

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, parameters

I'm using `.htaccess` to remove `index.php` from the URL and use its parameters with a `/` (slash).

For example, before:

```
example.com/index.php?id=posts
```

after:

```
example.com/posts
```

I'm also using `.htaccess` to allow `/` (slash) in the parameters like: `example.com/posts/mypost`, where `posts / mypost` is an `index.php` parameter!

But my problem is that when I access the parameter with a `/` (slash) like: `example.com/posts/mypost` it loads the page but without loading the CSS, it only works if I use without the `/` as in `example.com/posts` or just a string with no bars! But if I DELETE this part of the `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php

RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

The parameter with `/` slash works, however using `index.php?Id=` like: `example.com/index.php?id=posts/mypost`. But it's not what I want, I want to remove the `index.php` and use the parameters of him with `/` slash!

My `.htaccess` complete code:

```
#remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L] 

#use parameters without " ?id= "
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?index.php$ - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]

#allow " / " slash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d 
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?id=$1 [L,NS]
```

Comment: When calling your css file do you have a slash at the beginning of the path or are you using an absolute path?

Comment: @imvain2 It does not have slash, my problem I think is that it goes to an alternative path, so it does not load the includes, for example when I enter mydomain.com/ posts/mypost it's like if posts were a path and not "posts/mypost" a parameter

Comment: If you are calling your CSS file without a leading slash and without it being called as an absolute path, the CSS file is being loaded as a file from the path in the address bar.

Comment: Im using <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

Comment: Check the network traffic in the browser - what is the URL of the CSS file the browser is requesting (for which you are presumably getting a 404)?

Comment: no include is loaded, neither css, nor js, nor includes!

Comment: Check this related question on the Webmasters stack: [.htaccess rewrite URL leads to missing CSS](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

And your URL is: `example.com/posts`

your browser is looking for: `example.com/posts/css/style.css`

By simply changing it to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
```

No matter how many folders deep you go, the browser will always go to the root for the file.

so `example.com/posts` will look for `example.com/css/style.css`

so `example.com/posts/more/and/more/and/more` will still look for `example.com/css/style.css`.

Comment: Still the same :/

Comment: After almost a day I solved the problem, you helped me damn, thank you brother: D could you edit your answer so I accept it and give an upvote? I had to use /mydomain/css/style.css